# How do I jump or goto a line in Kakoune?

Tags: text-editors, kakoune

In vim I can do this with colon followed by the line number, e.g. `:5`. How do I do this in Kakoune?

Comment: Had this question recently and thought I'd share here since I didn't see an answer on SuperUser or StackOverflow. I see the question is getting downvoted, so if it'd be more appropriate elsewhere, please let me know! SuperUser and StackOverflow are [my frequent learning places for vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380635/vim-how-to-go-to-exact-line-on-ubuntu), so I figured it'd be good to post Kakoune related things here.

Answer (score 3):

`5g`

Enter the number followed by the goto key.